# Do $L^P$ functions form a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a general question about $L^P$ functions.

I have heard that $L^P$ functions form a vector space. My question is can we make them form a metric space too? And what is/are the possible metric/s ? I am mostly concerned with functions in complex plane and a possible metric in terms of a norm in the vector space.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Top of a Google search gives http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space.

Comment: Why not? If you define the metric $d$ on $L^p$as $d(u, v)=\|u-v\|_{L^p}$ for $u$, $v\in L^p$.

Comment: @user40615 It can happen that $u \ne v$ but $\|u - v\|_p = 0$. However, this can be fixed to make $L^p$ a metric space.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Thank you for the comment, could you please elaborate? I know that in $L_2$ the usual norm $||u-v||_2$ is zero even when $u$ and $v$ are not the same in a countable set of points. But then they claim $u$ and $v$ are $L^2$ equivalent. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Instead of considering individual functions in $L^p$, you consider the equivalence classes of the relation $u \sim v \iff u = v \text{ [a.e.]}$. When you talk about a function $u$ in the metric space $L^p$, you're really talking about the equivalence class of all functions that are equal to $u$ [a.e.]. This is how you ensure that $d(u, v) = 0 \iff u = v$.

Comment: I understood it, thanks.

Comment: Made my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a metric space, it is required that $d(u, v) = 0$ iff $u = v$. This is not immediately true for functions in $L^p$, for if $u \ne v$ but $u = v$ [a.e], then $\|u - v\|_p = 0$. This is easy to fix, however.

Instead of considering individual functions in $L^p$, you consider the equivalence classes of the relation $u \sim v \iff u = v \text{ [a.e.]}$. When you talk about a function $u$ in the metric space $L^p$, you're really talking about the equivalence class of all functions that are equal to $u$ [a.e.]. This is how you ensure that $d(u, v) = 0 \iff u = v$.

Comment: Thanks for completion the comment but  what you said is just definition of $L^p$.